# PINOUT ON LT1789CS8-1

Tags: integrated-circuit, pinout

the following in-amp IC is 8-lead plastic SO, but there is no indication about which pin is first pin (oreintation is not printed on the IC ) any information about how to determine it is good enough.

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Mind the chamfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LT1789 [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1789fc.pdf) (page 22) clearly shows that pin 1 is on the chamfered side:

[image: LT1789 physical from datasheet]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the datasheet to be sure, but it is very likely to be the bottom left pin in the IC the correct way up in the picture. This is because:

- The edge is chamfered down on that side, usually an indication that that is the pin 1 side.
- The text is orientated correctly.

Neither of these indications is standard, so **be sure to check the datasheet**!